# asp.net core publish issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, centos

i am trying to run mvc on centos, here i got a problem. After publishing my app and go to the publish folder and input "dotnet core.dll", it works well and website can be accessible. then i close my terminal(Xshell5), my website can not be accessible, but the process dotnet is still running in the background.
i tried another way with "dotnet run", then i close terminal , the website can still be accessible, can anyone tell me the reason, how can I use publish file running the website after i close my terminal ,thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write a script called web for instance，content：
"dotnet xxx.dll >/dev/null 2>&1 &"
save then add X privilege "sudo chmod +x web"
then "sudo ./web"
so it can run in the background

Answer (score 0):

Go to project folder and run:

```
nohup dotnet run &
```